# How to only show color choices for the data on the screen, not all data, in Spotfire

Tags: filtering, data-analysis, spotfire

I have some visualizations on Spotfire, that have a slider as X-axis, and by sliding it, data points get added or removed based on the current slider position.
The data points have colors, and they're shown in the legend pane. Now the pane shows all colors, regardless of whether the data points associated with these colors are on display or not.
How to limit the colors in the legend to only the ones on display at the current slider position?

I have tried inside the Color settings to choose "Current filtering only" for "Evaluate axis expression on:" instead of "All data" but nothing changed.
I'm pretty sure it needs a custom expression, but this is probably out of my knowledge.

Comment: Can you clarify how the slider works? If the slider is a filter, it should automatically remove the colours.

Comment: @gaiapaolini I wasn't the original creator of the dashboard, but it's set as a zoom slider, not filter. Is there a way to use the zoom value? Or it must be changed to a filter?

Comment: can you give more information about what visualization it is and what the variable on the slider is, etc. etc. Be as specific as you can, please.

Comment: @gaiapaolini the visualization shows some data relevant to multiple products over time. It has a line for each product, that has a specific color, and the slider shows a percentage of the associated values, sliding it should only show the data that are within the specified range of percentages.

Comment: I don't understand the way this slider is defined. That is what I was asking. Technical detail about the way this visualization is defined.

Comment: @gaiapaolini Sorry for coming back late, was on vacation. The slider is just a custom expression Y-axis, that's defined as zoom slider. The data points that appear or disappear are just really zooming in or out, not filtering.

Comment: In that case I cannot think of a way around it.

Comment: @gaiapaolini can I make it into a filter? Like can I use the same custom expression to make a filter, and use that as the Y-axis instead? Would that work?

Comment: potentially, but in order to help I would need some details on the custom expression and the plot and the data structure. I know data might be confidential, but if the information provided does not help create a reproducible example, I cannot help more.